# Monocle and Installation of DDRTree

Tags: r, bioconductor

I can't seem to install the bioconductor package 'monocle' for single cell RNA sequencing analysis.
My R version is 3.4.3, Bioconductor is 3.6.
I keep getting this error message, and installing DDRTree separately also fails. Do you know how I can solve this?
Many thanks.

> biocLite("monocle")
>   BioC_mirror: https://bioconductor.org
>   Using Bioconductor 3.6 (BiocInstaller 1.28.0), R 3.4.3 (2017-11-30).
>   Installing package(s) 'monocle'
>   also installing the dependency 'DDRTree'

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/DDRTree_0.1.5.tar.gz'

## Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 13728 bytes (13 KB)

downloaded 13 KB

trying URL 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.6/bioc/src/contrib/monocle_2.6.4.tar.gz'

## Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 9497904 bytes (9.1 MB)

downloaded 9.1 MB

- installing *source* package 'DDRTree' ...
  ** package 'DDRTree' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
  ** libs
  /opt/centos/devtoolset-1.1/root/usr/bin/g++ -std=c++11 -I/apps/well/R/3.4.3/lib64/R/include -DNDEBUG  -I"/gpfs0/apps/well/R/3.4.3/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/include" -I"/gpfs0/apps/well/R/3.4.3/lib64/R/library/RcppEigen/include" -I"/gpfs0/apps/well/R/3.4.3/lib64/R/library/BH/include" -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -g -O2 -c DDRTree.cpp -o DDRTree.o
  /bin/sh: /opt/centos/devtoolset-1.1/root/usr/bin/g++: No such file or directory
  make: *** [DDRTree.o] Error 127
  ERROR: compilation failed for package 'DDRTree'
- removing '/gpfs0/users/morris/u0302066/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/DDRTree'
  ERROR: dependency 'DDRTree' is not available for package 'monocle'
- removing '/gpfs0/users/morris/u0302066/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/monocle'

The downloaded source packages are in
        '/tmp/Rtmpcx6BJi/downloaded_packages'
installation path not writeable, unable to update packages: BH, ChIPpeakAnno,
  ChIPseeker, DBI, DEXSeq, DT, FNN, Formula, GEOquery, GGally, GOSemSim,
  GWASTools, GenomicAlignments, GenomicFeatures, GenomicRanges, Gviz,
  HardyWeinberg, Hmisc, ICS, ICSNP, MASS, MCMCpack, Matrix,
  MultiAssayExperiment, NCmisc, NMF, R6, RCurl, RMySQL, RSQLite, RSpectra,
  RUnit, Rcpp, RcppArmadillo, RcppEigen, RcppParallel, Rtsne, SPAtest,
  ShortRead, StanHeaders, VGAM, VariantAnnotation, VennDiagram, XML, ade4,
  amap, annotate, ape, argparse, bigmemory, bindr, bindrcpp, biomaRt, bit,
  blob, bookdown, caTools, chron, classInt, cli, cluster, coda, commonmark,
  cowplot, curl, data.table, desc, devtools, digest, doParallel, dotCall64,
  dplyr, e1071, edgeR, ellipse, ensembldb, erma, evaluate, ff, ffbase, fgsea,
  fields, foreign, futile.options, getopt, ggbio, ggfortify, ggplot2, git2r,
  glmnet, glue, gmp, gtools, hexbin, highr, hms, htmlTable, htmlwidgets,
  httpuv, igraph, inline, irlba, iterators, knitr, lambda.r, lattice, ldblock,
  limma, lmtest, logistf, loo, lubridate, maps, matrixStats, mclust, mgcv,
  mice, microbenchmark, mime, miniUI, mixOmics, munsell, mvtnorm, nlme,
  openssl, optparse, packrat, phangorn, pheatmap, pillar, pkgconfig, pkgmaker,
  plogr, plotly, plotrix, progress, psych, purrr, quantreg, rJava, ranger,
  reshape, rgl, rhandsontable, rjags, rjson, rlang, rmarkdown, rngtools,
  roxygen2, rpart, rprojroot, rstan, rstudioapi, rtracklayer, rvcheck,
  sandwich, scales, scater, scatterplot3d, sf, shape, shapes, shiny,
  shinyWidgets, shinydashboard, shinyjs, sm, snow, sourcetools, spam, spp,
  stringi, stringr, survey, survival, testthat, tibble, tidyr, tidyselect,
  truncnorm, units, utf8, viridis, viridisLite, withr, xgboost, xlsx, xml2,
  xtable, yaml, zoo
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages(pkgs = doing, lib = lib, ...) :
  installation of package 'DDRTree' had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages(pkgs = doing, lib = lib, ...) :
  installation of package 'monocle' had non-zero exit status

> 

Answer (score 0):

Found a work around assuming we had the same error.

Quit R,

If using windows delete the DDRTree package folder(s) in

```
\Users\USER\Documents\R\win-library\3.5
```

reload R, without any packages

run

`devtools::install_github("cole-trapnell-lab/DDRTree")`